# Movie about a radiatory dust exploration

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm asking for the name of a movie in which a new phenomena is found.
The field of dust, messes with physics and a team of scientists is sent in.
We follow the scientists. First they skip a few days, as time seems to work differently here. They meet morphed animals and plants. Eventually exploring an abandoned building, that a prior team of scientists had come to. They find their video camera and do an operation on one member to remove something thats growing inside him...

Think I remember the title being something like "evol", "revol" ...?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you see this?  Was it live-action or animated?  Was it in English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *[Annihilation](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2798920/)* (2018).

An all-female team of scientists is sent into *"the shimmer"* in order to investigate what happened to the previous teams and determine what's causing the phenomenon.

Comment: The "dust" part was throwing off my search... :)

Comment: The [TV Tropes entry](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Annihilation2018) has more info, but may take over your life.

Comment: I had it at "team of scientists" and "they skip a few days".

Comment: Thank yoou! 
Fuzzy Boots - you might be right on TV Tropes ;DD